# FOREIGN KEY to UNIQUE on one of two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two pretty simple tables.

```
-- Create a new table called '[Events]' in schema '[dbo]'
-- Drop the table if it already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Events]
GO
-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, -- Primary Key column
    [ImportTypeId] INT NULL
        REFERENCES [dbo].[ImportTypes](Id),
    [ImportId] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT UQ_Events UNIQUE (ImportId, ImportTypeId),
    INDEX IX_EventTitle ([Title] ASC)
);
GO

-- Create a new table called '[Events]' in schema '[eventful]'
-- Drop the table if it already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [eventful].[Events]
GO

-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE [eventful].[Events]
(
    [EventfulId] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Events](ImportId),
    [ImportDate] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE()),
    [LastImportDate] DATETIME NULL,
    [Url] NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_EventfulEvents PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EventfulId)
);
GO
```

However, this foreign key constraint is causing issues:

```
REFERENCES [dbo].[Events](ImportId)
```

When executing the script I'm getting the error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Events' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__Events__Eventful__5B78929E'.

How do I reference just the `ImportId` on that table? Do I need to have the `ImportTypeId` in the `[eventful].[Events]` table for this to work?

Comment: [ImportId] must be either an PK or unique in the table: [Events]

Comment: @FlavioFrancisco that is correct, but FOREIGN keys can be created against UNIQUE keys based on this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: But `ImportID` isn't defined as `UNIQUE` @MikePerrenoud. The combination of `ImportID` and `ImportTypeID` is.

Comment: @Larnu that's what I was wondering right? Do I need to have `ImportTypeId` in the `eventful` schema as well to define a compound `FOREIGN KEY` just so I can reference the `ImportId`. Painful, but if that's the only option, then that's doable for sure.

Comment: It's not painful, it's logical @MikePerrenoud. You've defined `ImportId` as non-unique (by lack of defining it as unique), so it can't be a key. That's one of the basics for key candidates.

Comment: @Larnu I guess when I think about it in the context of the `ImportTypeId` having to be part of the `UNIQUE` key in the `dbo` table it does make sense. I think in practice it's often going to be the case that these `ImportId` fields aren't likely to cross lines because they're coming from different vendors, I did feel the need to include the `ImportTypeId`. I guess I could composite the actual value of `ImportId` during import to ensure the key is `UNIQUE` across vendors and then it would only require one field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A FK must reference the PK or unique index. In your example `ImportId` is not unique:

```
CONSTRAINT UQ_Events UNIQUE (ImportId, ImportTypeId) != UNIQUE(ImportId)
```

You could:

1. Create an unique index on single column `ImportId`
2. Use composite FK relationship based on two columns

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=94c3050fdb74fdc6c514371fe0179f12)

Comment: Yep, it appears that's going to be about the only option is to add the `ImportTypeId` to the `eventful` schema so that I can build a compound `FOREIGN KEY` to that `UNIQUE KEY`.